# Query - Sending public and private messages to users

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to implement the delivery of public messages for all users and personal messages.

Simplified tables:

```
messages
+---------------+---------------------------+
| Field         | Type                      |
+---------------+---------------------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned          |
| admin_id      | int(10) unsigned          |
| type          | enum('public','targeted') |
| subject       | text                      |
+---------------+---------------------------+

messages_read_status
+----------------+---------------------------------+
| Field          | Type                            |
+----------------+---------------------------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned                |
| message_id     | int(10) unsigned                |
| user_id        | int(10) unsigned                |
| status         | enum('unread','read')           |
+----------------+---------------------------------+
```

When sending  *public*  messages - in  *messages_read_status*  table records not created. For  *targeted*  messages - creating record with  *unread*  status. When message is read by user - setting  *read*  status.

Two filters on client side - Read/Unread. Message *type* does not matter for user.

**Main task** - create query to request Read or Unread messages for user, regardless of the *type* of message.

The main problem is to handle in query request for *public unread* messages, because there can be no records for them in *messages_read_status* . UNREAD query works properly while some user reads the message. Then new record in *messages_read_status* created and other users can't see this message any more. This situation I can't resolve. READ query works correctly.

```
SELECT  messages.* FROM messages
LEFT JOIN messages_read_status 
ON messages.id = messages_read_status.message_id
WHERE
{OTHER FILTERS} AND
(messages_read_status.`id` IS NULL OR (messages_read_status.`user_id` = $user_id  AND messages_read_status.`message_status` = '$message_status'))
```

samlpe sql - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d940d

Thank you

Comment: +1 for the sqlfiddle.com link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way to get Unread (public + targeted)

```mysql
SELECT  messages.* FROM messages
LEFT JOIN messages_read_status
ON (
    messages.id = messages_read_status.message_id AND
    messages_read_status.`user_id` = $user_id
)
WHERE
{OTHER FILTERS} AND
((messages_read_status.`id` IS NULL AND messages.type='public') OR messages_read_status.`status` = 'unread')
```

AND for Read using simpler rules

```
{OTHER FILTERS} AND messages_read_status.`user_id` = $user_id AND messages_read_status.`status` = 'read'
```